# How To Serve Dynamic Objects From Odata In MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, dynamic, odata

I am writing a generic rest service against a json database. I would like to serve my data as IQuerable OData. Do to the nature of the data, my objects are untyped dynamic objects. For instance :

```
 [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<dynamic> GetObjects()
    {
        return db.BigListOfJsonStrings
            // returns dynamic object
            .Select(o => System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(o))
            .AsQueryable();
    }
```

Now this does not work, but you get an Idea of what I am going for. The exception received is

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'propertyName' on type 'System.Object

I inspected the objects being returned, and they are in-fact type-less. They are JsonDynamicObjects a type of string dictionary (like the ExpandoObjects).

This said, what is the next step I need to take to resolve this issue ? Do I need to write a custom query provider or a custom OData provider or something ? A link to the correct documentation would be helpful.

**Edit**

For the time being I have this solution using dynamics on hold. I have achieved partial OData support by deserializing the objects as JObjects and manually applying the ODataQuery. It is not an ideal solution, but it works.